# RPG Multiple Status Effects

Tags: java, enums

The class that I am trying to implement will handle the different status effects for a character. Think Pokémon, a Pokémon can both be paralyzed and poisoned.

For this I was first thinking of having a file with all different status effects stored, all being `public final static List<String> effects`. Then I wanted to try and do it as a `bitfield` instead. Not sure after I tried this which is the best approach, however that is a question for CodeReview and not StackOverflow. Now I want this piece of code to work.

```
public class CharacterStatus {

    public static final int EFFECTS_MAX = 7;

    public enum StatusFlags {
        DEAD        (1<<0),
        PARALYZED   (2<<0),
        SLEEPING    (3<<0),
        CONFUSED    (4<<0),
        POISONED    (5<<0),
        BURNING     (6<<0),
        FROZEN      (7<<0);

        private final long status;

        StatusFlags (long status) {
            this.status = status;
        }

        public long getStatus () {
            return status;
        }
    }

    public CharacterStatus () {
        // declare a Status Flag with all bits set to 0
    }

    public setBit (String effect) {
        // It should set the correct bit Based on DEAD, PARALYZED etc
    }

    public clearBit (String effect) {
        // It should clear the correct bit Based on DEAD, PARALYZED etc
    }

    public setBit (int b) {
        // It should set the correct bit Based on DEAD, PARALYZED etc
    }

    public clearBit (int b) {
        // It should clear the correct bit Based on DEAD, PARALYZED etc
    }

    public long getValue () {
        return statusFlags.getStatus();
    }

    public String getValueAsString (String d) {
        String s = "";
        d = "|";

        int currentEffect = EFFECTS_MAX;

        for (int i = EFFECTS_MAX; statusFlags.getStatus() > 0; i--) {
            if (statusFlags.getStatus() > Math.pow(2, i)) {
                // load effect #i based on the StatusFlags
                s+= EFFECT#i + d;
            }
        }

        s.substring(0, s.length()-d.length());

        return s;
    }
}
```

A lot of this code is dummy code, for example `s+= EFFECT#i + d;` should get the name of the flag based on which number `i` has.

Mini version of `Character.java`

```
public abstract class Character
{
    // alive and well
    private final CharacterStatus characterStatus = new CharacterStatus ();

    /**
     * @return  the status of this character
     */
    public CharacterStatus getCharacterStatus () {
        return characterStatus;
    }
}
```

Clarification: What I want to work is to store `StatusFlags` for `Character` and be able to manipulate and print the different flags. For example in combat A casts a poison attack on B. Which will result in `B.getCharacterStatus().setBit("POISONED");`

Comment: Why do you take a string for a status instead of a `StatusFlags` value? Parsing the string is needless work, and passing in an element from `StatusFlags` ensures that you don't pass an invalid value.

Comment: what is the question, "Now I want this piece of code to work." is a little bit broad, no?

Comment: Take a close look at those bit-shifts again, you're shifting e.g. the bit-pattern of the value `5` zero times (which does nothing). Instead of `5 << 0` you should have `1 << 4` (as the bit-numbers are zero-based)

Comment: Why not just an `EnumSet`?

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo that I don't mind really mind. However I want to later on load statuses externally, meaning I have to parse it somewhere.

Comment: @Emz Then an `enum` is an inappropriate type. Try an `AbstractStatus` with each of the statuses being a subclass (which also allows you to define the status effect on the status itself).

Comment: So the list approach I had at first would be better suited for this task?

Comment: Yes a list would be better. And even better would be a list of objects, then each object can keep track of effect expiration-time and other things as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a modification that uses an EnumSet instead of bit flags. Modified to be self-contained (I wrote it in ideone).

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class CharacterStatus
{

    public  enum StatusFlags {
        DEAD,
        PARALYZED,
        SLEEPING,
        CONFUSED,
        POISONED,
        BURNING,
        FROZEN;
    }

    private EnumSet<StatusFlags> status; 

    public EnumSet<StatusFlags> getStatus () {
        return this.status;
        // you could return another format if you like, e.g., string array
    }

    public String toString() {
        String s = "";
        for (StatusFlags stat  : this.status){
            s+= stat.toString()+"\n";
        }
        return s;   
    }


    public CharacterStatus () {
        this.status = EnumSet.noneOf(StatusFlags.class);
        // declare a Status Flag with all bits set to 0
    }

    public void setBit(StatusFlags effect) {
        this.status.add(effect);
        // It should set the correct bit Based on DEAD, PARALYZED etc
    }

    public void clearBit (String effect) {
        this.status.remove(effect);
        // It should clear the correct bit Based on DEAD, PARALYZED etc
    }


    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        CharacterStatus status = new CharacterStatus ();
        status.setBit (StatusFlags.CONFUSED);
        System.out.println(status.toString());
    }
}
```